# How to find an asp.net client is disconnected immediately

Tags: c#, asp.net, client

I'm aware of `Response.IsClientConnected` but in my scenario it has a great lag. Code:

```
// sample code for sending a dynamic file in chuncks

long bytesSent = 0;

while (continueSending)
   {
      if (!AskReceiverToContinue())
         break;

      if (!Response.IsClientConnected)
         break;

     // Your suggestion goes here... :)

      try
      {
         Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
         bytesSent += buffer.Length;
      }
      Catch
      {  // To my experience, this is more reliable than Response.IsClientConnected
         continueSending = false;
      }
   }
```

The problem is the actual received bytes by client is very smaller in amount than my `bytesSent`. It seems when a client gets disconnected my program finds out the situation with a great lag (and continue increasing `bytesSent`) and this is because ASP.NET tells me the situation (client is disconnected) late.

Is there any reliable method for finding out when a client has been disconnected (real-time) ?

Comment: Just curious: why do you care for such thing?

Comment: Because it's more fair to charge my clients traffic-basely. But it seems I cannot move to such a solution !

Comment: you can if you use a client that explicitly connects over tcp/ip, meaning a progam the user would've to download. Your plan isn't possible via a webpage.

Comment: What about Java or Flash? They might have better control over such things. Some websites giving access to big files even ask the client to install activeX control.

Comment: @Shadow: And most power users refuse to install that activeX es

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are transfering over HTTP, aren't you? If yes, there is no way due to the statelessness of the HTTP protocol. Only thing you have to help you is the timeout, which you are already using.

Comment: Yes, I'm using HTTP. As I know, there's a underlying `TCP` connection. Why ASP.NET doesn't update `IsClientConnected` as soon as the `TCP` connection is closed ? Can I access the native handle or something like that ?

Comment: Even if this were possible, it wouldn't change a thing as the TCP connection would only be closed if the client timed out. If the client doesn't tell you that he is gone, you have no chance of seeing it bar a timeout.

Comment: Then how rapidshare.com counts the users traffic ?

Comment: I guess they are estimating it given the users speed over time.