# ASP.NET Web API + Long running operation cancellation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Is there a way to figure out in ASP.NET Web API beta whether the HTTP request was cancelled (aborted by user of for any another reason)? I'm looking for opportunity to have a kind of cancellation token out-of-the-box that will signal that the request is aborted and therefore long-running ops should be aborted as well.

Possible related question - the use case for the CancellationTokenModelBinder class. What's the reason to have a separate binder for cancellation token?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could check `Response.IsClientConnected` from time to time to see if the browser is still connected to the server.

Comment: This seems to be from ASP.NET MVC stack, not from ASP.NET MVC Web API. Please correct me if wrong.

Comment: This is from core ASP.Net engine. Only works with IIS integration pipeline (not VS debug mode).
MSDN covers a good documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.isclientconnected.aspx

Comment: thank you for suggestion. This seems to be the only option, I'll probably build solution basing on this.

Answer (score 9):

I'd like to sum-up a bit. The only approach that seem to work is checking Response.IsClientConnected.
Here some technical details regarding what is going behind the stage: 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094735/when-is-response-isclientconnected-slow) and [here](http://forums.iis.net/t/1187030.aspx)
This approach has some flaws:

- Works only under IIS (no self-hosting, no Dev Server);
- According to some SO answers may be slow (do not react immediately after client disconnected): [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056988/how-to-find-an-asp-net-client-is-disconnected-immidiately);
- There are considerations regarding this call cost: [here](http://www.guidanceshare.com/wiki/ASP.NET_2.0_Performance_Guidelines_-_Design_Considerations)

At the end I came up with the following piece of code to inject CancellationToken based on IsClientConnected into the Web API controller:

```
    public class ConnectionAbortTokenAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly string _paramName;
    private Timer _timer;
    private CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;
    private CancellationToken _token;

    public ConnectionAbortTokenAttribute(string paramName)
    {
        _paramName = paramName;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        object value;
        if (!actionContext.ActionArguments.TryGetValue(_paramName, out value))
        {
            // no args with defined name found
            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
            return;
        }

        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        if (context == null)
        {
            // consider the self-hosting case (?)
            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
            return;
        }

        _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _token = _tokenSource.Token;
        // inject
        actionContext.ActionArguments[_paramName] = _token;
        // stop timer on client disconnect
        _token.Register(() => _timer.Dispose());

        _timer = new Timer
        (
            state =>
            {
                if (!context.Response.IsClientConnected)
                {
                    _tokenSource.Cancel();
                }
            }, null, 0, 1000    // check each second. Opts: make configurable; increase/decrease.
        );

        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }

    /*
     * Is this guaranteed to be called?
     * 
     * 
     */
    public override void OnActionExecuted(System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        if(_timer != null)
            _timer.Dispose();

        if(_tokenSource != null)
            _tokenSource.Dispose();

        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also there is an option to use SignalR and similar solutions, but they're a bit out of scope for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you added CancellationToken in to controller methods, it will be automatically injected by the framework, and when a client calls xhr.abort() the token will be automatically cancelled

Something similar to

```
public Task<string> Get(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
```

For MVC you can also refer to

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.IsClientConnected
HttpContext.Response.ClientDisconnectedToken
```

For .NetCore

```
services.AddTransient<ICustomInterface>(provider => { 
     var accessor = provider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>);
     accessor.HttpContext.RequestAborted;
  });
```